# How to enhance the visualisation of my survplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survival

I'm conducting an experiment (during 10 days of observation) to compare four different conditions named NTS, NTC, TS, and TC. I performed a logrank test, and the differences between the conditions seem to be statistically significant. I am aware that the death rate in my experiment is very low, but are there any ways to enhance the visualization of my data?

Here is my R script:

```
morta <- read.csv("mortality.csv", head=TRUE, sep = ";")
surv_obj <- Surv(morta$Time, morta$Statut)
survdiff(formula = surv_obj ~ Condition, data = morta)
```

Here are the results of my logrank test :

```
N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
Condition=NTC 1200     1069     1087    0.2821     26.46
Condition=NTS 1200     1156     1145    0.1120     10.69
Condition=TC  1200     1126     1130    0.0134      1.27
Condition=TS  1200     1137     1127    0.0900      8.54
Chisq= 35.4  on 3 degrees of freedom, p= 1e-07
```

My data set contains 5 columns which are named : ID, Statut, Time, Condition and Colony.
ID : the ID using to refer to an individual (not realevant here).
Statut : 0 or 1, 0 is for dead and 1 for alive.
Time : the day of the death and 10 if still alive at the end of the experiment.
Condition : information on condition (NTS, NTC, TS and TC)
Colony : from 1 to 6, just the label of the colony.

[Result of my ggplot2 using ggsurvplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82yzN.png)

Thank you for your awnsers and sorry for my English it is not my first language,
Louis

I was expecting a clear separation between the different conditions, something like this :

[What I was expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh3i9.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your at-risk table you will notice that the event rate is very low. The NTC group has a value of 1102 at day 10 suggesting that there were only ~9% of individuals experiencing an event.

1102/1200 = 91.8%, so if you constrain the y-axis using the `ggsurvplot` argument `ylim = c(0.85, 1)` you might be able to observe the separation in your groups that you were hoping to visualise.

This is of course very different to the expected graph which does not have constraints on the y-axis.